# Why does NavigationLink inside a Button work, but not vice versa in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

In SwiftUI, if you embed a NavigationLink inside a button, then clicking the button will trigger the button's action and the navigation as well.

```swift
    struct LoginView: View {
        @StateObject private var viewModel = LoginViewModel()
                Button(action: viewModel.doLogin, label: {
                    NavigationLink(value: viewModel.userInfo) {
                        Text("Log in")
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(.plain)
                })
                .buttonStyle(.plain)
    }
```

However the reverse only triggers the button's action. Why is that?

```swift
    struct LoginView: View {
        @StateObject private var viewModel = LoginViewModel()
                    NavigationLink(value: viewModel.userInfo) {
                        Button(action: viewModel.doLogin, label: {
                            Text("Log in")
                        })
                      .buttonStyle(.plain)
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(.plain)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the `Button` is created, it takes a `label:` parameter in its initialiser that is, in this case, of type view.

So what gets dispalyed on the screen is the `label`.

In the first case, the label is a `NavigationLink` and clicking on a it performs the navigation.

In the second case, the `NavigationLink` has the `label` parameter, that displays a `Button` and because of the style, it completely hides the navigation link area, as opposed to, if you had used a `Text` view or so.

So the answer is, the `NavigationLink` simply does not get clicked on because it hides entirely beneath the `Button`.